# Angular material Tabs title unwanted behavior

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have encountered this weird behavior using `MatTabsModule` of Angular Material.  Tabs title stretch when I click on a tab though I have no error in the console.

#### app.html

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link>
    Tab1 (click me to see the bug)
  </a>
  <a mat-tab-link>
    Tab2
  </a>
</nav>
```

I repeat there's no error in the console. My dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "5.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

For everything else

Here's a [Stack-blitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rexsuj?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: Yup, definitely see the same issue. I tried out the more general `<mat-tab-group>`, to see if it was specific to the `<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>` approach (which is meant to be specific to using the router-outlet). But there's the same jump for the tab-group ([StackBlitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tabs-debugging)). If you step into the dev tools Source tab, and manage to pause execution while the jump is occurring, you can see that there's an additional div appended next to your link, which it looks like is supposed to animate, but isn't.

**Edit**: Got it. Answering now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Angular Material module requires using some theme to style its components. These styles also affect transformations, and thus the way animations are handled. So without including a theme, you'll see jumps in your elements. The themes are pretty fully customizable, but if you just want to get started with the basic, they recommend using a default.

So include this in your `styles.css`, as long as your project is using the Angular CLI:

`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

Reference: [Angular Material Getting Started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme)

[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tabs-debugging)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a theme added in your angular.json file maybe you haven't re-start the local server after adding the material module. Just stop the server with 'ctrl+c' and then serve it again. Now, the material component should behave properly considering you have imported the component in the 'app.module' file.